# I Want to send data to one page and display another page in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am building a flutter app in which on click of a Gridview Cell I want to display a new page and send the id of the grid cell to a different page, other than the display page. How to do that with Navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just pass the content to the next page via its constructor. The Gridview Cell has an `onClick` handler I think, if not you can wrap it using a `GestureDetector` and use the onTap method there and do something like that:

```
onClick: () => {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => SecondPage(id),
    ),
  );
}
```

where id is a variable stored in the GridviewCell. It comes down to how you structure the data in the widget really.